# Is possible to use container's size as priority_queue's priority in C++?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  priority_queue<vector<int>> q;
  q.push({1, 2, 3});
  q.push({3});
  q.push({1, 2});
  q.push({0, 1, 2, 3, 4});

  while (!q.empty()) {
    cout << q.top().size() << endl;
    q.pop();
  }
}
```

The above code will output

```
1
3
2
5
```

I want to get

```
1
2
3
5
```

I searched around but not able to figure out the correct way or not sure it's possible. Any help will be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), something like this might work:

```
// Using lambda to compare elements.
auto cmp = [](const std::vector<int> &left, const std::vector<int> &right)
{
    return left.size() < right.size();
};
std::priority_queue<std::vector<int>, std::vector<std::vector<int>>, decltype(cmp)> q(cmp);
```

Comment: You'll probably want `cmp` to take these vectors by reference, otherwise pretty much every operation on such a queue will result in obscene amounts of vector copying.

Answer (score 2):

While constructing `priority_queue`, you can provide your own compare function.

Please see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

```
// Using lambda to compare elements.
auto cmp = [](int left, int right) { return (left ^ 1) < (right ^ 1); };
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> q3(cmp);
```

Just change the types per your requirement